# Checkbox standard value

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I just have a checkbox. If I do nothing at all with the checkbox I want to hide something and use a function. But once I selected the checkbox I want to show something and use another function. All the solutions are for when you uncheck. I don't want that! What must I do?

```
$('#leveringscheck').click(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $('#adres').show();
    tweedeadres();
  } else {
    $('#adres').hide();
    gewoonadres();
  };
});
```

Comment: what is the problem that you are facing exactly?

Comment: Well it won't do my function in the else section without i have to select the checkbox and unselect it....

Comment: So you want the code to run upon page load, without the user having to click the checkbox?

Comment: yes exactly that i want

Comment: uppercase  "I"  is much easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Try to invoke the click handler manually after binding it,

```
$('#leveringscheck').click(function(){
 var res; $('#adres').toggle((res = this.checked, res));
 if (res) { tweedeadres(); }else { gewoonadres(); };
}).click();
```

This snippet will execute the click event handler immediately after binding the click event to the target element.

Comment: @Wesley C'mon. You said "Exactly" to a user who suggested what i have written in my answer. Can you add more details related to what you want more than this?

Comment: Ok here it is: i have this page with a checkbox. If my user does nothing at all with this checkbox it will do a funtion and hide something. Once my user press one time on this checkbox to select it it will do another function.